# Convert only few columns from Excel to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets in an excel file and am trying to convert all those 3 sheets into a single pdf file using VB script.

It's working fine with my code below.

```
Sub CreatePDff()

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", " Sheet2", " Sheet3")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\sample.pdf", _
    openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Now, I need only columns (A to D and G, J) to convert from sheet3. Not the entire columns from Sheet3.

I need entire data from Sheet1, Sheet2 and only selected columns from Sheet3 into a single pdf file.

Any ideas on this

Comment: Just hide columns E,F and H, export pdf and eventually unhide columns :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sheet and have the columns A-D and G-J pasted over there. Lets assume it is Sheet4. And in the Array, pass Sheet4 instead of Sheet3 and delete the sheet4.

**Modified your code**

```
Sub CreatePDff()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set sh = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' Adds a new sheet

sheets("Sheet3").Range("A:D,G:J").copy 'Copy Selected data from Sheet3
sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").pastespecial ' Paste it in new sheet

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", " Sheet2", " Sheet4")).Select 'Change sheet3 to 4
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\sample.pdf", _
    openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False
  
Sheets("Sheet4").SelectedSheets.Delete 'Delete Sheet4

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: The Add method is returning an error "runtime error 1004, method add of object sheet failed". Any ideas on this, please?

Comment: See the edited code. I assume you only have 3 sheets. And this is creating a new sheet, which will be sheet4. If you have more than 3 sheets, then you need to give a name to the new sheet i.e sh.name="Anyname". And at the end delete by Sheets("Anyname").SelectedSheets.Delete